# RSA encryption in NativeScript

Tags: rsa, nativescript

I am working on a Nativescript-Angular application, I need to send one parameter of my web-request encrypted. We are using RSA encryption in all other platforms.

I have searched a lot on the internet regarding the same, I have already tried the node-RSA from npmjs.com but it gives

> Failed to Find module: "Crypto"

Comment: Crypto is a Node modules which is not supported by the NativeScript runtime. Did you look at `crypto-browserify` instead?

Comment: I am using "node-RSA" for RSA encryption of my password, node-RSA internally uses "Crypto"

Comment: Yes I got that.

Comment: Actually there is no NS plugin I am aware of that fulfills your requirements. How about implementing this natively by yourself?

Comment: I managed to make it work with nativescript by using JSEncrypt

Comment: Hello @KevinDias Could you share your solution please?